# Notation of small $n$ in the production of muons in cosmic rays

Tags: particle-physics, notation, leptons, cosmic-rays

I came across this page in the "Cosmic rays and particle physics" by Gaisser. I cannot find any explanation to the notation of $n$ (eqn. 6.8 and forward). Intuitively it should be something like no. of particles, number density etc. but according to 6.11 it should be in units m/s.

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page2]

Comment: Note from (6.6) and (6.7) that mass, momentum, and energy all have the same units. That's the $c=1$ convention. In that case, (6.11) suggests that $\mathrm dn$ is dimensionless, since you have $\mathrm dE$ and $P$ in the denominators on each side.

Comment: n seems to be the number of particles of a given type. example $n_γ$ .